# Delete item with partition key & range key - DynamoDB

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have a DynamoDB table with the following attributes:

```yaml
SubscriptionsTable:
    Type: AWS::DynamoDB::Table
    DeletionPolicy: Retain
    Properties:
      TableName: ${self:custom.subscriptionsTableName}
      AttributeDefinitions:
        - AttributeName: eventName
          AttributeType: S
        - AttributeName: hookUrl
          AttributeType: S
      KeySchema:
        - AttributeName: eventName
          KeyType: HASH
        - AttributeName: hookUrl
          KeyType: RANGE
```

I would like to delete an item according to its `hookUrl` and `eventName`. That's the code of my repository:

```js
const deleteSubscriptionFromRepository = async ({
  hookUrl,
  eventName,
}: {
  hookUrl: string;
  eventName: SubscriptionEventName;
}) => {
  const mapper = getDatabaseMapper();

  try {
    return await mapper.delete(Object.assign(new SubscriptionModel(), { hookUrl, eventName }));
  } catch (e) {
    throw new DatabaseAccessError(e.message, 'deleteSubscriptionFromRepository');
  }
};
```

Instead of using directly the DynamoDB client, I'm using the `DataMapper` from `'@aws/dynamodb-data-mapper';`

But I'm receiving the following error:

```
  DatabaseAccessError: The number of conditions on the keys is invalid
```

How is that possible to delete an item according to its partition and range key? What I'm doing wrong in the above code?